# jquery carriage return not retained when sent in data-attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, attributes

I am trying to retain the carriage return that is inside of a data-attribute.  When the attribute is sent over to index.php, the div no longer recognizes the line breaks and it prints out all of the text in one large paragraph.

Here is how the HREF looks that contains the attribute:

```
 <?php

 $current .= 
 ($i == 1 && $sformat != 'table' && ( $key != $unique_id || $unique_id == '' ) )?"$count. 
 <a data-toggle=\"modal\" class=\"open-RestrictModal\" href='#my-restrictModal' 
 data-description=\"".$row["description"]."\" ">".${$key}."</a></dt>":'';

 ?>
```

And here is the javascript in index.php that gets the data-attribute and turns it into a javascript variable, then sends it to a modal window:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on("click", ".open-RestrictModal", function () {
    var myDescription = $(this).data('description');
    $(".modal-body #description").text( myDescription );
   });
  </script>
```

As stated, the problem is, when it is displayed in the modal, there are no longer any carriage returns.  I need to get those carriage returns.

This is closest to what I've been trying to do:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9131941d-232b-4592-9b13-c0348cf2a83d/how-can-i-send-data-containing-line-break-n-in-jquery-ajax?forum=scripting

This one too:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-does-the-jquery-val-method-strip-carriage-returns-from-a-textarea-value

Please help.

Comment: carriage returns are essentially meaningless in html* if you want to display new lines, use either `<br>` or wrap in `<p>` tags

Comment: @Steve Not true. In a lot of browsers the CRLF character can be used to display multiline tooltips

Comment: That's the problem. I am not sure where to put the <br> tag. I think it has to be done in the javascript, but I'm not sure where I can put it.

Comment: @RGraham hence the * in my comment. I know there are cases such as being considered content in a textarea, or effecting the layout of inline elements (or indeed tooltips) but i dont think that is the case with the OP

Comment: @Steve You're right, my comment was not relevant to this case (and I thought your * was a mismatched italic flag :))

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried giving your `#description` element a style of `white-space: pre` or similar?

Otherwise you'll have to replace carriage returns with HTML line breaks: `myDescription.replace('\n', '<br>')`

Also, I wouldn't output literal carriage returns in a HTML attribute (in XML it's forbidden I think)

So you should make that replacement in PHP: `str_replace("\n", "<br>", $row["description"])`

Finally, you're not escaping your output correctly. What if your description field contains quote symbols `"` or other special HTML characters? You should always use an appropriate escaping function, such as `htmlspecialchars()`.